# how to set the src of an iframe from a popup that was opened from that iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, window, location

I have an `iframe` from which a open a pop-up window. After some redirects in that pop-up, I want to change the `src` of the `iframe`, and close the pop-up. This is not working in Chrome (in other browsers is working). I am trying with `window.opener.location.href=newURL`, but in Chrome this changes the `href` to the page, not the `iframe`. Any suggestions? I am not a javascript developer, but this is a little part needed for my project.

Comment: Is it only Chrome issue? Btw, after the popup redirects a few times, does it end up on the same host when it tries to change the opener location?

Comment: yes. in the other browsers is working correctly. The iframe src is changed with the new value. Should i try with self.opener.location.href?

Comment: the popup is used to allow an application to share google credentials (sso login)

Comment: Have you looked at [iframe popup refresh parent window not working in chrome or safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604626/iframe-popup-refresh-parent-window-not-working-in-chrome-or-safari)?

Comment: thanks. my search was different. i will try that

Comment: Wait, are you saying that it changes the location of the page that holds the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it may have something to do with security imposed by Chrome.
You could write function for changing url (a simple wrapper around assigning window.location), and than invoke that function from your popup window instead of directly trying to mess with opener location.

```
// function in parent (opener window)
function navigateTo(url) {
    window.location = url;
}

// invoke that function from within pop-up like so:
window.opener.navigateTo('http://some-url.com');
```

It will work provided both parent window and pop-up share the same domain at the time function above is executed.

Comment: Ok, so you cannot use window.opener (at least in Chrome) - you'll get security error.